# Report doesn't preview in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

Hi I am working on already existing reports in SSRS, to do some formatting stuff (changing the look) on the report.

My issue is when i am trying to preview the report it doesn't work, instead it opens the 'Save File As' window and asks me to save the file in "UTF - 8 Solution File (*.sln)" in the reports folder, the folder from where I am accessing the reports. When I cancel that, it throws an error in the preview window as "An error occurred during local report processing. An error has occurred during report processing".

What am I missing here? Can anyone help me with this.

Thank you.

Comment: I believe SSRS auto saves an rdl upon preview, or at least can be set to that.  If you have permissions issues writing to the default directory it would make sense you are getting the error you describe.  Beyond that, we'd need to know more information.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I believe that is what it is asking for, I saved .sln file of the report and it then previewed the report. But I don't know why that happened. This is the first time ever i have encountered with that kind of problem.